# identify the week second purchase was recorded for each customer ID

Tags: sql

please help me in SQL

I want to findout weekno the second purchase was made for each customer ID

here purchaseyn column value 1 means purchase made and 0 means not made

Table customerinfo

```
Week_No         customerID      PurcahseYn
201643                1              0
201643                2              1
201644                1              1
201644                2              1
201645                1               1
```

I want output like

```
Weekno CustomerID  
201645   1
201644   2
```

Many thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS so the following is standard SQL:

```
select week_no, customer_id
from (
  select week_no, customer_id,
         row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by week_no) as rn
  from customerinfo
  where purchaseyn = 1
) t
where rn = 2;
```

The above uses a window function number the purchases done by each customer and then restricts the overall result to the second one.

Comment: thanks Sql works .I have slightly differ requirement.If I want count number of   week their second purchase made .What should be the sql pls help me . many Thanks